# Unable to containerise varnish, throws error "Service Unavailable"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, devops, varnish

varnish.local.php

```
<?php
return [
    'acsi_varnish' => [
        'clients' => [
            'cache' => [
                'endpoint' => [
                    'host' => 'dev-varnish',
                    'port' => '8443',
                    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

---

default.vcl

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "dev";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

---

docker-compose-template.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dev:
    image: dev:centos7
    container_name: dev
    hostname: dev
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR}
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    privileged: true
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.2
    ports:
      - 443:443
#     - 6082:6082
      - 9001:9001
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
      - 29015:29015
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:127.0.0.1
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-mysql:
    image: dev-mysql-5.7:latest
    container_name: dev-mysql
    hostname: dev-mysql
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_MYSQL}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_MYSQL}
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.3
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE:${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:127.0.0.1
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-mongo-3:
    image: mongo-3.0:dev
    container_name: dev-mongo-3
    hostname: dev-mongo-3
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO_3}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO}
    privileged: true
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.4
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:127.0.0.1
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-mongo-4:
    image: mongo-4.4:dev
    container_name: dev-mongo-4
    hostname: dev-mongo-4
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO_4}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_MONGO}
    privileged: true
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.5
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:127.0.0.1
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-solr-6:
    image: solr-6.6:dev
    container_name: dev-solr-6
    hostname: dev-solr-6
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.6
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:127.0.0.1
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-solr-8:
    image: solr-8.6:dev
    container_name: dev-solr-8
    hostname: dev-solr-8
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_SOLR}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_SOLR_8}
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.7
    ports:
      - 8984:8983
    environment:
      - SOLR_HEAP=2g
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:127.0.0.1
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-rethinkdb:
    image: rethinkdb
    container_name: dev-rethinkdb
    hostname: dev-rethinkdb
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_BIND_MOUNT_DIR_RETHINKDB}:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_RETHINKDB}
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.8
    ports:
      - 28015:28015
      - 8080:8080
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:127.0.0.1
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-memcached:
    image: memcached
    container_name: dev-memcached
    hostname: dev-memcached
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.9
    ports:
      - 11211:11211
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-memcached:127.0.0.1
      - dev-varnish:172.100.0.10

  dev-varnish:
    image: varnish:7.2.1-alpine
    container_name: dev-varnish
    hostname: dev-varnish
    user: '0'
    volumes:
      - "./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl"
    ports:
      - "6082:8443"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/varnish/varnishd:exec
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.10
    extra_hosts:
      - dev:172.100.0.2
      - dev-mysql:172.100.0.3
      - dev-mongo-3:172.100.0.4
      - dev-mongo-4:172.100.0.5
      - dev-solr-6:172.100.0.6
      - dev-solr-8:172.100.0.7
      - dev-rethinkdb:172.100.0.8
      - dev-varnish:127.0.0.1
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9

networks:
  dev-online:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.0.0/24
```

I am trying to containerise the varnish service which is already working in "dev" container, but after i containerise, i don't see it is working, i am not sure what is going wrong here.

the connection should work in the below flow

https://loadwebsite.com -> "dev" container -> "dev-varnish" container -> "dev" container

the browser throws the error below

```
"Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Please run run `docker compose ps dev-varnish` to see if the `varnishd` process is running
- Finally run `docker compose exec -ti dev-varnish varnishlog -g request` to run the `varnishlog` binary inside the container and output the logs

Please attach the output from `varnishlog -g request` to your question. This will clarify how Varnish is behaving and can lead to a possible solution.

Comment: 1. docker compose ps dev-varnish 

NAME                COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
dev-varnish    "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   dev-varnish    running             80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6082->8443/tcp, :::6082->8443/tcp

2. docker compose exec -ti acsi-dev-varnish varnishlog -g request --> gives no output (cursor blinks continuously )

Comment: @RajsekarReddy in that case there's probably no issue with Varnish. The problem occurs before the request reaches the Varnish container. Please debug your Dev container and see how it connects to Varnish. Hopefully that container has the necessary logs to help you debug.

Comment: Okay, got the point, thanks for the quick reply, will debug as suggested